# Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'num_neighbor' at row 1

Tags: mysql

[Some lines of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvXVS.png)

I am trying to import csv file to mysql.

'''

```
CREATE TABLE nash_house (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    unnamed_id INT,
    parcel_id VARCHAR(255),
    land_use VARCHAR(255),
    address VARCHAR(255),
    suite_num INT,
    city VARCHAR(255),
    sale_date DATE,
    price INT,
    legal_ref VARCHAR(255),
    vacant VARCHAR(255),
    multi_parcel VARCHAR(255),
    owner_name VARCHAR(255),
    owner_address VARCHAR(255),
    owner_city VARCHAR(255),
    owner_state VARCHAR(255),
    acreage DECIMAL(7,2),
    tax_district VARCHAR(255),
    num_neighbor INT,
    image VARCHAR(255),
    land_val INT,
    building_val INT,
    total_val INT,
    finished_area DECIMAL(6,5),
    found_type VARCHAR(255),
    yr_built INT,
    ext_wall VARCHAR(255),
    grade VARCHAR(255),
    num_bed INT,
    num_full_bath INT,
    num_half_bath INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I made a table with this code and tried to import with

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'nash_house.csv' INTO TABLE nash_house
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@suite_num, @owner_name, @owner_address, @owner_city, @owner_state, @acreage, @tax_district, @num_neighbor, @image, @land_val, @building_val,
@total_val, @finished_area, @found_type, @yr_built, @ext_wall, @grade, @num_bed, @num_full_bath, @num_half_bath)
SET suite_num = IF(@suite_num = '', NULL, @suite_num),
    owner_name = IF(@owner_name = '', NULL, @owner_name),
    owner_address = IF(@owner_address = '', NULL, @owner_address),
    owner_city = IF(@owner_city = '', NULL, @owner_city),
    owner_state = IF(@owner_state = '', NULL, @ownerstate),
    acreage = IF(@acreage = '', NULL, @acreage),
    tax_district = IF(@tax_district = '', NULL, @tax_district),
    num_neighbor = IF(@num_neighbor = '', NULL, @num_neighbor),
    image = IF(@image = '', NULL, @image),
    land_val = IF(@land_val = '', NULL, @land_val),
    building_val = IF(@building_val = '', NULL, @building_val),
    total_val = IF(@total_val = '', NULL, @total_val),
    finished_area = IF(@finished_area = '', NULL, @finished_area),
    found_type = IF(@found_type = '', NULL, @found_type),
    yr_built = IF(@yr_built = '', NULL, @yr_built),
    ext_wall = IF(@ext_wall = '', NULL, @ext_wall),
    grade = IF(@grade = '', NULL, @grade),
    num_bed = IF(@num_bed = '', NULL, @num_bed),
    num_full_bath = IF(@num_full_bath = '', NULL, @num_full_bath),
    num_half_bath = IF(@num_half_bath = '', NULL, @num_half_bath);
```

When I use
`LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`, I get Error 1265.
However, when I use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`, I do not get error, but no data get imported.

May I get help to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: That error doesn't mean that the data is not imported. It's probably just telling you that the value datatype in that row doesn't match with the column datatype.

Comment: *Some lines of csv file* [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). PS. `column = IF(@variable = '', NULL, @variable)` should be simplified to `column = NULLIF(@variable, '')`.